# Grid does not call action method to fill data in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Can someone help me to resolve the issue of filling Kendo UI Grid in mvc on IE platform?

The following are technologies used:
1) Telerik Kendo UI version 2015.1.408.545
2) MVC 5.0, razor view
3) .Net Framework 4.5

In Chrome whenever MVC View page loads it calls read action method twice. First call is for getting scema to be bind to the Kendo UI Grid. Second time is for getting data to fill Kendo UI Grid. All this requests from Controller to View and vice versa works fine in Chrome.
But when I run this application in IE (11.0), then first time it displays all the data properly. But when the request posted for another data it does not call the action method twice. Therefore the previous data is being displayed on Grid. Thats the issue.

**View**

```
@model CustomReportResultsViewModel 

@(Html.Phoenix().Grid<DataTable, DataTable>()     
    .DataSourceReadController("CustomReport", "Reports") 
    .KeyName("ID") 
    .RecordName(Model.RecordName) 
    .CacheEditorTemplate(false) 
    .Columns(columns => { foreach (DataColumn c in Model.DataTable.Columns) { }}) 
)
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ResultsGrid(int id, string recordName) { 
    return PartialView("ResultsGrid", new CustomReportResultsViewModel { DataTable = GetData(id, true), RecordName = recordName }); 
}

// List 
public JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var table = GetData();
    var result = table.ToDataSourceResult(request);

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, 3);
}

private string GetDataSource(StringBuilder columnSchema, StringBuilder aggregates, StringBuilder group, string primaryKey, string read) { 
    var dataSource = new StringBuilder(); 
    dataSource.Append("{transport:{"); dataSource.Append("read:{type:\"GET\",url:\"" + read + "\"}"); dataSource.Append("},");
    dataSource.Append("type:\"aspnetmvc-ajax\",");
}
```

Comment: I already tried by keeping cache to false. It worked well. But performance got down. So I can not keep cache to false. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How do you request the data? AJAX call? Would be better if you added the grid datasource code / controller methods. Narrow the question, please.

This grid/controller signatures always worked for me on IE.

Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]        
        public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            //whatever it takes to get that data, like
            var data = repository.GetAll<Model>();
            return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

View:

```
@using Entites.Model

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
        .Name("grid")                   
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
        {
            dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Home"));
        })
)
```

Comment: We make AJAX call to load data. BTW we are dynamically creating kendo ui script

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to suggest anything more without seeing the actual code. :/

Comment: @model CustomReportResultsViewModel

@(Html.Phoenix().Grid<DataTable, DataTable>()
.DataSourceReadController("CustomReport", "Reports")
.KeyName("ID")
.RecordName(Model.RecordName)
.CacheEditorTemplate(false)
.Columns(columns =>
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in Model.DataTable.Columns)
    {
        
    }
})
)

Comment: public ActionResult ResultsGrid(int id, string recordName)
        {
            return PartialView("ResultsGrid", new CustomReportResultsViewModel { DataTable = GetData(id, true), RecordName = recordName });
        }

        // List 
        public JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var table = GetData();
            var result = table.ToDataSourceResult(request);

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, 3);
        }

Comment: private string GetDataSource(StringBuilder columnSchema, StringBuilder aggregates, StringBuilder group, string primaryKey, string read)
        {
            var dataSource = new StringBuilder();
            dataSource.Append("{transport:{");
            dataSource.Append("read:{type:\"GET\",url:\"" + read + "\"}");
            dataSource.Append("},");

            // type needed to format request data to work with DataSourceRequestAttribute
            dataSource.Append("type:\"aspnetmvc-ajax\",");
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick reply.
We are following the below code:

```
 public ActionResult ResultsGrid(int id, string recordName)
 {
     return PartialView("ResultsGrid", new CustomReportResultsViewModel { DataTable = GetData(id, true), RecordName = recordName });
 }

 // List 
 public JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
 {
     var table = GetData();
     var result = table.ToDataSourceResult(request);
     return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, 3);
 }

 private string GetDataSource(StringBuilder columnSchema, StringBuilder aggregates, StringBuilder group, string primaryKey, string read)
 {
     var dataSource = new StringBuilder();
     dataSource.Append("{transport:{");
     dataSource.Append("read:{type:\"GET\",url:\"" + read + "\"}");
     dataSource.Append("},");
     dataSource.Append("type:\"aspnetmvc-ajax\",");
 }
```